# Azure Storage - Copy container with all contents using Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Storage [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) for Node.js for manipulating with blobs from my node express app but I didn't find an option to copy a container along with all blobs inside it.

Is there a way to do this from node app with this or any other library?

P.S. Node app is not deployed on Azure, it runs on an independent server.

Answer (score -1):

Storage SDKs doesn't provide methods to copy all blobs from a container to another.

You could use [DMlib SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) to copy, it's .net/.net core compatible and optimized for copy operations.

For tools, you could use legacy [AzCopy (written in .Net core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux) or [AzCopy V10 (written in Go)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10), within one command, you can finish a copy.

Comment: How can these tools be used or invoked from node or express.js app?